# Interpretation of coefficients in ECM for consumption

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics, consumption

Say that we are regressing consumption $C_t$ on time $Y_t$. Furthermore, suppose that both series are $I(1)$ and are co-integrated.

Given this, we set up the error correction model (ECM) as follows: $$\Delta C_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \Delta Y_t + \theta(C_{t-1} - \gamma_0 - \gamma_1 Y_t) + u_t$$ which is estimated using the 2-step Engle-Granger approach.

My question is: What is the economic interpretation of $\gamma_1$? Surely we cannot interpret this as the marginal propensity to consume (MPC)? I interpret it as describing the long-run equilibrium of the system.

However, I'm struggling to explain why this is the case, since mathematically: $$\gamma_1 = \frac{\partial C_t}{\partial Y_t}$$ which is exactly the definition of the MPC.

---

On [the Wikipedia page on ECMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_model#An_example_of_ECM), they describe $\gamma_1$ as the average propensity to consume (APC), which makes a lot more sense to, but which doesn't sit well with me since mathematically: $$\text{APC} = \frac{C}{Y}$$ and clearly that is not the definition of $\gamma_1$ since: $$\frac{C}{Y} = \frac{\gamma_0}{Y} + \gamma1$$

Could someone help me sort out my confusion?

Comment: I think there is an error in your formula. Shouldn't it be $\Delta Y_t$  rather than $Y_t$ outside of the long-run relationship and inside it should be $Y_{t-1}$. As it currently stands your long-run coefficient of interest is unidentified and the equation is econometrically unbalanced since $\Delta C_t$ is of lower order integration than $Y_t$ which will force $ \beta_1 =0$.

Comment: Also $\gamma_0$ is not identifiable separately from $\beta_0$ so that might be part of your problem in terms of interpreting the coefficients.

Comment: @Andrew M: I think the OP might be using $Y_t$ for what is usually ( in the literature ) $X_t$ and $C_t$ for what is usually $Y_t$. But you might be correct. I'm not sure because I'm not used to that notation.

Comment: @AndrewM Yep - I've edited the typo. Re identification, there is plenty of empirical work which does so, for instance: https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/-/media/boe/files/working-paper/2003/the-dynamics-of-consumers-expenditure-the-uk-consumption-ecm-redux

Comment: @TheveshTheva : The coefficient multiplying the $\theta$ still isn't time aligned in that $C_t$ is one step behind  $Y_t$.

Comment: @TheveshTheva if you start from the model $C_t$ = $\beta_0$ + $\beta_1$ $Y_t$ + $\alpha$ $C_{t-1}$ then the equivalent ECM representation is $\Delta$ $C_t$ =  $\beta_0$ + $\beta_1$ $\Delta Y_t$ + ($\alpha$-1)($C_{t-1}$- $\frac{\beta_1}{1-\alpha} Y_{t-1}$) which implies that $\gamma_0=0$ . Alternatively it can written as  $\Delta$ $C_t$ = $\beta_1$ $\Delta Y_t$ + ($\alpha$-1)($C_{t-1}$- $\frac{\beta_0}{1-\alpha}$ -$\frac{\beta_1}{1-\alpha} Y_{t-1}$ ) which implies that $\gamma_0\neq0$. Both representations are equivalent.